# Not able start spring boot version 3.1.0 application after migration

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, migration

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne (org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue and org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.BinderHelper.checkMappedByType(BinderHelper.java:1086)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.isReversePropertyInJoin(CollectionBinder.java:1571)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.noAssociationTable(CollectionBinder.java:1582)
    at 
 @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer"})
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "employeepersonaldetails")
 @EntityListeners(EntityListener.class)
 public class EmployeePersonalDetails extends BaseModel{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;

@ManyToMany
@OrderColumn
@JoinTable(name = "UserRole",
joinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name="empdbid")},
inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name="role")} )
private List<Role> roles;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "delegatedTo")
@OrderColumn
private List<EmployeeDelegations> employeeDelegations;
```

}

I have tried by adding below dependency to override coming version of hibernate 6.2.2 from springboot-stater. but it didn't work

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.5.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: To override the remove that dependency and add `<hibernate.version>6.2.5.Final</hibernate.version>` to your `<properties>` section in your pom.xml. Although I doubt it fixes the issue, as that is with your mapping. If it doesn't solve it, please update your question with your pom and entities.